# Скорочені, розмовні та зменшувальні форми імені Сергій

Tags: власні-назви

У російській мові широко використовується скорочене ім`я Сережа (від Сергей). Чи існує відповідник в українській мові?

У словнику знайшла такі форми (Л. Г. Скрипник, Н. П. Дзятківська. Словник-довідник «Власні імена людей», видання 3-тє, виправлене. Київ, 2005 (перевидання книги 1996 року)):

Розмовні та зменшувальні форми: Сергі́йко, Сергі́єнько, Сергі́єчко, Сергі́йчик, Сергу́ня, Серьо́га, Серьо́жа, Сєрьоня, Сєрьончик, Сєрий.

Тут є форма Серьожа. Але вона майже не використовується, наскільки я знаю.

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть запитання: спочатку ви запитуєте, «Чи існує відповідник в українській мові?», а потім вказуєте на наявні у словниках «Розмовні та зменшувальні форми». Ці форми чимось не підходять? Чим саме?

Answer (score 1):

Із статті Вікіпедії "Сергій"

***[Розмовні та зменшувальні форми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9)***:

> *Сергі́йко, Сергі́єнько, Сергі́єчко, Сергі́йчик, Сергу́ня, Серьо́га,
>   Серьо́жа, Сєрьоня, Сєрьончик, Сєрий*

Із словника-довідника «Власні імена людей» (Л. Г. Скрипник, Н. П. Дзятківська; Київ, Наукова думка, 1-е видання 1996 або [3-є видання 2005](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Dziatkivska_Nina/Vlasni_imena_liudei_Slovnyk-dovidnyk/)), [с. 98](//books.google.com/books?id=NFVmAAAAMAAJ&q="%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2+%D1%83+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C") (також з помилками розпізнавання [зацитованого на Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/54/53409/363577.html)):

> СЕРГІ́Й лат.; рим. родове ім'я — Sergius; можливо, від servus —
>   служитель. *Сергі́йко, Сергі́єнько, Сергі́єчко, Сергі́йчик, Сергу́ня,
>   Серьо́га, Серьо́жа.*

Comment: Щодо останньої цитати (зі Словопедії) маю підозру що "Серіієчко", "Сербига" та "Серьижа" - помилки сканування. На підтвердження - там у фамілії "Яновський" стирчить дефіс від переносу: "Ю. Янов-ський", а у прикладах є "Серьожа" та "Серьога".